# phpMyAdmin error #2002 "Cannot log in to the MySQL server", but works from console

Tags: linux, mysql, phpmyadmin

The MySQL service on my CentOS 6.3 server works well. I'm using phpMyAdmin-3.5.8.1 from default repository. I have sites that can connect to the databases and are using them successfully.

I can also connect to the database server using the `mysql -u... -p.... -h....` command.

The database is NOT on the localhost but another server.

Tried both hostname and IP in `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '10.188.8.207';`

I also have a lot of free space available.

The user is not `root`, `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';`

Edited:
I hit the same issue on another server, but the message is a bit different:

```
#2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

But I have

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.100.219';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
```

Next, I add a bit of garbage to the top of config.inc.php: I expect to see syntax error but nothing happened, thus I think phpMyAdmin just does not see/use this file.

```
ls -l config.inc.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 3981 Sep  3 07:59 config.inc.php
```

I have no ideas. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. are you trying to log in with root? 2. did you change configuration of pma? 3. do you use mysql from default repo? 4. netstat -anp|grep mysq|grep LIST 5. rpm -V phpMyAdmin mysql-server

Comment: Check your config for what it's using to connect. Make sure it's `tcp` and not `socket`.

Comment: Have just edited the question, User is not root, $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

Comment: @GioMac 2. the only configuration change is host afaik but I can post config if needed 3. unknown, it is installes by hosting provider and I have user assess only (to MySQL, but root locally) 4.mysql is NOT on the local box 5. S.5....T.  c /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
S.5....T.  c /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
phpMyAdmin.conf was changed because I use not the default /phpMyAdmin location

Comment: `getenforce` :)
I think httpd is not allowed to db connect by selinux

Comment: @GioMac wordpress works pretty well on the same apache/database

Comment: still, `getenforce` and double-check config.inc.php - problem is in selinux or config.inc.php. pastebin.com

Comment: # getenforce
Disabled

http://pastebin.com/gvG5najZ (comments removed)

Comment: you are missing port option. also, better use mysqli extension. Looks like there's huge difference between original and this file. overwrite with original one (from package) and change ip, port, socket to tcp and mysql to mysqli

Comment: @GioMac here http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#port mentioned default port 3306 and in config.sample.inc.php port is absent as well. Nevertheless I started with config.sample.inc.php, add host and port and got the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it eventually! Perhaps this will work for PMA from rpms only.

Despite PMA itself is in `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin` it expects to have `config` dir at `/var/lib/phpMyAdmin/` and config in `/etc`

Solution: just edit `./libraries/vendor_config.php` and set the correct paths or

`ln -s /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php /var/lib/phpMyAdmin/config/`

Edit 3 months later:
On another server it checks /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php instead of /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php - so added this hard link and it works well now.

Comment: where did you hardcoded /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php ? i can't find a solution to this problema

Comment: @LachezarRaychev try to find vendor_config.php

Answer (score 0):

On an Amazon Linux server (i.e. Amazon's RHEL-like distribution) it looks for the config file in /etc/phpMyAdmin as the poster above described.